# Why do I need to clear a stringstream variable with each iteration of a loop in which it is used

Tags: c++, loops, stringstream

At my school we have to follow a style guide which states we must declare each variable at the top of the function where it is used, as opposed to right before it is used. This often means you have to reset or clear variables while using them inside loops since they are not declared inside that loop. I don't understand why a stringstream variable needs to be "clear"ed with each loop iteration and was hoping someone could shed light on this. I know *how* to clear it just want to know *why* it's necessary.

Comment: Your style guide is crazy.

Comment: Best practices usually state the exact opposite of your style guide.

Comment: To answer your question, can you give an example that can be commented upon?

Comment: It depends on what the local variables are. Pulling variables out of a loop can prevent multiple constructor and destructor calls, and can improve performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rationale behind this is that creating *heavy* objects inside of the loop leads to performance degradation. `::std::stringstream` is one of these objects and it's a common mistake to create and destroy string streams all the time. However such a rule does not apply for *light* objects, such as primitive types.

Consider the [test case](http://ideone.com/Msnv1a):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    auto const loops_count{1000000};
    auto const p1{high_resolution_clock::now()};
    {
        stringstream ss{};
        for(auto i{loops_count}; 0 != i; --i)
        {
            ss.str(string{}); // clear
            ss << 1;
        }
    }
    auto const p2{high_resolution_clock::now()};
    {
        for(auto i{loops_count}; 0 != i; --i)
        {
            stringstream ss{}; // recreate
            ss << 1;
        }
    }
    auto const p3{high_resolution_clock::now()};
    cout << duration_cast< milliseconds >(p2 - p1).count() << "ms "
        << duration_cast< milliseconds >(p3 - p2).count() << "ms" 
        << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

first loop 35ms, second 431ms

Comment: Thank you! Answered my question perfectly!